# copying data from one DB to another DB

Tags: sql, perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures

I am writing a perl script which copies data from few tables present in DB1 to tables present in DB2.
I have a table in DB3 which contains insert query for each table present in DB2.

Below is an eg query for one table.

```
Insert into ACTION_BLOCK
 (ACTION_BLOCK_ID, RULE_EXPR_ID, ACTION_BLOCK_ORDER)
 Values();
```

I thought of implementing below logic

1. Read data from DB1 for a table and load result to an hash.
2. For each element in the hash

   - Replace values() keyword in insert query with values('data in hash')
   - Execute the insert query in DB2.

But data in DB might contain date as well. In that case I can't directly replace `values()` keyword in the query with `values('data in hash')` as I need to mention the format of date (like `dd\mm\yyyy` after the value).
Can anyone help me how to overcome this challenge.

To make it more clear consider below eg.:

> `DB1` and `DB2` have a table called `ACTION_BLOCK`. I need to copy data present in `DB1_ACTION_BLOCK` table to `DB2_ACTION_BLOCK` table.

According to my logic,I pick insert query for `ACTION_BLOCK` table from `DB3` which will be as below.

```
Insert into ACTION_BLOCK
 (ACTION_BLOCK_ID, RULE_EXPR_ID,RULE_DATE,ACTION_BLOCK_ORDER)
 Values();
```

In the above query I replace the "values()" keyword with th data I got from `DB1` which is as shown below:

```
values(01,02,02/02/2016,09);
```

This will throw me error as the date format is not correct. Ideally it should be as shown below:

```
values(01,02,to_date('02/02/2016','mm/dd/yyyy'),09);
```

But my hash which contains the data from `DB1` will just have the date without that `to_date` keyword and format.

I hope this example clearly depicts the problem.

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Can you create a complete example with stuff that is in all three databases, and what the expected output is supposed to be?

Comment: Are you saying that `DB3` contains actual SQL code?

Comment: DB3 contains insert queries for each table in DB2.

Answer (score 0):

In pure SQL, you would just write:

```
INSERT INTO DB2.dbo.ACTION_BLOCK
select * from DB1.dbo.ACTION_BLOCK
```

Just wrap that up in Perl, and Bob's your uncle!